# What architecture/technology can I use for picture recognition?

Tags: image, architecture, image-recognition

I want to build an Android and Iphone App that can use picture recognition. Before starting with any App development I wanted to start with the algorithms that can recognize pictures. I was thinking using Apache Spark and later embed the methods into a JavaEE project. I heard of  openCV but I am uncertain if that will work.

My use case would be to recognize photos with its motives. As simple example would be a picture of different houses and then recognize them.

I worked a little bit with Spark and thought about classifiers and neural networks.

What frameworks/libraries could be used to start the development?

Comment: Yes, it's commonly done with neural networks, with assists, and lots of training data.

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback. So guess I need to start to read about neural networks and spark's implementation.